# Ordering by multiple columns in Prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I know currently **Prisma** doesn't support ordering by multiple scalars fields, (see this issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/62).
But, I'm wondering if there is someone who found a solution to work around this issue without using executeRaw mutation (raw **SQL**) because I have many places in my code where I need to order by multiple fields and I don't want to use executeRaw in so many places.
I will appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Since Prisma 2.4 this should be basically possible by using array in orderBy:

```
const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
   select: {
      email: true,
      role: true,
   },
   orderBy: [
      {
         email: 'desc',
      },
      {
         role: 'desc',
      }
   ],
})
```

Find more in docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#sort-user-by-multiple-fields---email-and-role

Comment: Ok, but how do I write `... ORDER BY (foo = 1) DESC, bar ASC, foo ASC, baz ASC;`?

Comment: What do you mean by (foo = 1) ?

Comment: I want rows where foo equals to 1 be sorted before the rest. In SQL you can do that as I've written it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a solution, In my project, I need random order, increment/decrement, aggregation... use raw finally.